# Loading words/strings from a .txt file

Tags: perl

I've written a basic Perl script for generating all possible unique combinations of a set of words:

```
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my $strings = [qw(GGGG CCCC TTTT AAAA)];
my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

I was wondering if anybody could possibly point me in a good direction on how I may go about loading the strings from a .txt file rather than manually adding them (GGGG CCCC TTTT AAAA etc.). I should state that I am rather new to Perl.

I was also wondering if anybody could explain why the output contains a space between the words:

```
GGGG CCCC
GGGG TTTT
GGGG AAAA
CCCC TTTT
CCCC AAAA
TTTT AAAA
```

Is this due to the way in which I have separated the strings?

**UPDATED:**

Just to update RE: importing from a .txt file and to put it here incase it ever helps any other beginner, i've written and am now using this:

```
open (my $data, "<", "test.txt") or die "There was a problem opening: $!";
my @primers = <$data>;
close $data;
chomp @primers;
use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my $strings = \@primers;
my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Comment: Regarding the file, you should reads Quentin's link and try around. If you are having trouble, come back and create a new, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your spaces: the method `$iter->next` seems to return an array ref that contains two values. In the first row, that is `[ 'GGGG', 'CCCC' ]`. If you put an array into a string (`print "@foo"`) it gets stringified. That means, all the elements will be joined into one string. Perl uses the variable `$"` to do the join.

```
print "@$c\n";
```

is the same as saying:

```
print join( $", @{ $c }) . "\n";
```

By default, `$"` contains a space ().

---

You can read up on `$"` in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Here is what it says:

> `$"` When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a
>   double-quoted string or a similar context such as `/.../` , its
>   elements are separated by this value. Default is a space. For example,
>   this:
>
> ```
> print "The array is: @array\n";
> ```
>
> is equivalent to this:
>
> ```
> print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";
> ```
>
> Mnemonic: works in double-quoted context.

Comment: I've ended up replacing my original print-line with: print join('',@$c) ."\n";

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can go through various link suggesting how to write to a file ..! Moreover you are getting speces in between because you are printing an array in string context(known as stringfying it )